# Failed to fetch Maven dependency javadoc with Bazel

Tags: java, maven, maven-2, maven-3, bazel

**WORKSPACE file**

```
maven_jar(
name = "jdoc",
artifact = "javadoc:javadoc:1.3",
)
```

**Error message** after Bazel build

```
 no such package '@jdoc//jar': Failed to fetch Maven dependency: Could not find artifact javadoc/javadoc:javadoc:jar:1.3 in jdoc (https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/)
```

**Question:**

Why the `artifact` become `javadoc/javadoc:javadoc:jar:1.3`? `javadoc/javadoc:javadoc:1.3` is expected.

The javadoc:javadoc:1.3 repo does exit at https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/.

[image]

Comment: @starcorn Thanks for your attention. I use bazel as building tool instead maven. Relevant code is in the WORKSPACE file.

Comment: Based on the docs it looks Ok..bit it might be helpful to post the full error output and may be the full build file...

Comment: Ah..the problem is that this artifact is only a pom file and **not** a `jar`. You are trying to pull a jar file which does not exist. It's only a pom file nothing more...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The javadoc:javadoc:1.3 does not exist at maven repository. 
[image]

After clicking Download(JAR), A 404 page appears.

I am confused by the error message returned by `bazel`.

Answer (score 3):

I wrote the maven_jar rule.  Unfortunately, "Could not find artifact javadoc/javadoc:javadoc:jar:1.3 in jdoc" is the error message Bazel gets from the Maven API (see [the code](https://github.com/bazelbuild/bazel/blob/master/src/main/java/com/google/devtools/build/lib/bazel/repository/MavenJarFunction.java#L220-L221)).  I've filed [a bug](https://github.com/bazelbuild/bazel/issues/1105) to see if we can make this any clearer, particularly in this case.